# Expo Router with custom index.html file

Tags: html, expo, react-navigation

I was previously able to customize the `index.html` file for Expo by editing `web/index.html`. But ever since I've upgraded to Expo Router the default `index.html` file takes over and my changes don't seem to do anything.

How can I change the default `index.html` file while using Expo Router?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It's under `public/index.html` instead of `web/index.html` now. https://docs.expo.dev/guides/customizing-metro/